# Existential quantifier versus Universial quantifier, from a natural language perspective

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic, quantifiers, logic-translation

I am aware about the difference between existential quantifier and universal quantifier and it is always clear for me when to use them,

if the statement starts either with **There** is/are **some** ..." or "**Everyone**/..."

but now I have this statement:

If **some** people are nicer than any people in area1 , than they must live in area2.

This is the FOL translation:

> **∀x.** (people(x) ^ ∀y.(people(y) ^ in(y,area1) **→** nice(x) > nice(y)) → in(x,area2)

1. Why should I use the universal quantifier when in the statement it talks about some. Should it not be **∃x.**
2. Why is it  **→** nice(x) > nice(y) and not  ^ nice(x) > nice(y)

Comment: Ambiguities of natural language... If we write it as $\exists x [people(x) \land \forall y ( \ldots ) \to in(x,area2)]$ we are forced to assume that there are some people. In natural language, the statement "if some people are ...", it sounds possible that there are none.

Comment: and regarding question two, if I would use a conjunction then it would mean that all "y" are people, who are not "nice(r)" but the statement is just saying if for all y who live in area2, then those are not nice(r). Is it correct how I distinguish between the two connectives?

Comment: Because with the $\land$ you would be saying that everything is a person (including the areas!), and lives in area 1 and is less nice than the $x$ .... (including $x$ itself)!! No, you want to to be saying:  *if* we are dealing with something that is a person and living in area 1, then $x$ is nicer than it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement can be thought of as:

> "If some person is nicer than everyone in area1, then they live in area2"

... which can also be thought of:

> "If any one person is nicer than everyone in area1, then they live in area2"

... and now you start to see the connection with the universal: the sentence is really about *anyone*, i.e. everyone

A little more technical is the following explanation:

At first, the original sentence looks like a conditional, with the antecedent being an existential claim, i.e. something like:

$\exists x [person(x) \land \forall y ((person(y) \land lives(y,area1)) \rightarrow nicer(x,y))] \rightarrow lives(x,area2)$

but the problem with this is that the $x$ in $lives(x,area2)$ is a free variable, and so this is not a sentence. Instead, we realize that the sentence is not a conditional, but a quantified sentence.  OK, so should we just extend the scope of the existential to get:

$\exists x \big([person(x) \land \forall y ((person(y) \land lives(y,area1)) \rightarrow nicer(x,y))] \rightarrow lives(x,area2) \big)$

But that isn't right either: now you're basically saying that there is *something* such that *if* it is a person nicer than anyone in area 1, then that something lives in area 2 ... well, that would trivially be true if we pick for that something anything that is not a person! (which is why you almost never see an existential of a conditional).  Indeed, maybe at this point you realize that this should really be a universal:

$\forall x \big([person(x) \land \forall y ((person(y) \land lives(y,area1)) \rightarrow nicer(x,y))] \rightarrow lives(x,area2) \big)$

That is, we end up saying:

> "For any object ... if that object is a person nicer than anyone in area 1, then that person lives in area 2"

... and yes, now we realize that that is just a more convulated way of expressing te original sentence. Or rather: that the original English sentence is a more efficient way of expressing this logic sentence)

Here is another English sentence that makes a similar contraction:

> "If a dog wags its tail, then it wants to play"

Now, do you think that this is about *some* dog?  It says "a" dog, and indeed, it is about *one* dog ... but it is really about *any one* dog, i.e. *any* dog, i.e. *all* dogs. Indeed, it should be clear we should translate this as:

$\forall x ((dog(x) \land WagsTail(x)) \rightarrow WantsToPlay(x))$

For your second question:

If we use the  $\land$, i.e.

$\forall x \big([person(x) \land \forall y ((person(y) \land lives(y,area1)) \land nicer(x,y))] \rightarrow lives(x,area2) \big)$

then you would be saying that everything *is* a person (including the areas!), and lives in area 1 and is less nice than the $x$ .... (including $x$ itself)!!

No, you want to to be saying: *If* we are dealing with something that is a person and living in area 1, then $x$ is nicer than it .. we want to exclude anything that is not a person or not living in area 1.

Comment: I really appreciate the very detailed answer!

Comment: @xava You're welcome!  This is a common difficulty in translating from English! :)